# Prove there is homography between a line and algebraic set

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, differential

Let $D_1$ and $D_2$ be two distinct lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$. Show that there is a homography $h$ such that $h(D_1)=V(X,Y)$ and $h(D_2)=V(Z,T)$.

I don't know how to find the homography. I know that $h:=z\mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ is an homography. But how to show homography between $D_1$ and $V(X,Y)$? Similiarly, for $D_2$ and $V(Z,T)$?

Comment: I believe a homography here is given by the action of invertible $4\times 4$ matrices on ${\bf A}^4$ (which give automorphisms of ${\bf P}^3$). The lines $D_1$ and $D_2$ correspond to planes in ${\bf A}^4$ so you need to find an invertible matrix, which sends a given plane to another given plane. This is a problem of linear algebra.

Comment: The homography you mention corresponds to the action of the matrix $(a,b;c,d)$ on ${\bf A}^2$, which gives an automorphism of ${\bf P}^1$.

Comment: What is the setup of matrix equation?  How do I represent $D_1$ and $V(X,Y)$ so I can equate $V(X,Y)$ with product of matrix and $D_1$?

Comment: These correspond to subspaces of dimension 2 in a vector space of dimension 4. Choose bases of these subspaces and find a linear operator which maps one base to the other.